# Is there a way to have three level grouping in a list group view?

Tags: list-view, grouping

Currently SP has the facility to do two level grouping. However, I have a request to do three or more than three levels of grouping at some times.

Is there a built-in configuration or hack to do this?

Answer (score 5):

This can be done, but requires SharePoint Designer. There are some excellent blog posts by Mike Smith about it ([for 2007](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2008/11/sharepoint-group-by-on-more-than-2.html) and [for 2010](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2011/01/sharepoint-group-by-on-more-than-2.html)).

The steps are too long to detail here, but suffice to say it is possible.